# Deleted SQL folder in Program files, now program needing SQL wont launch, or reinstall

Tags: sql

I got a little click happy and deleted the SQL folder out of Program files not think if it's connection to a design application I am using. I have tried uninstalling SQL Server 2019 by using the installer and then using the remove option. I have tried manually uninstalling it by deleting all instances of it off my drive. According to the vendor of the design software, when it is installed, SQL Express should automatically be installed. However, this part of the installation  [fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WjtB.jpg) with the attached error. I have tried manually installing SQL server, but during launch of the application it says it cannot locate the local server with error 26.

I am at the point of contemplating wiping my drive and re-installing Windows. Something is staying around and causing an issue but I cannot find what that is as I have followed all guides to removing SQL and have worked with the vendor who remoted into my computer to try and fix the issue. They were unable to identify the issue.

Comment: You can’t have both a paid edition of SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server Express installed on the same system. Have you tried uninstalling whatever edition you have installed and manually installing the correct version of SQL Server Express this application is expecting to exist. Obviously you should perform a reboot if you haven’t already done so

Answer (score 0):

> I ..... deleted the SQL folder out of Program files ...    I have
> tried manually installing SQL server, but during launch of the
> application it says it cannot locate the local server with error 26.

While you should not have two versions of SQL installed, deleting the program from the Program folder has done some damage.

You can try a Repair Install and Keep Data. This keeps the User Profile as well.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. In this case, use the prompt to Keep Data.

If this does not work, then back up the system completely and reinstall Windows.